# Visual Studio have many delay before start to building and some time be stop again

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build

We have a moderately sized solution, with about 20 projects. In one of them I have my business entities. On compiling any project, visual studio waits and hangs about one and a half minutes on this BusinessEntities project.

I tried our solution in SharpDevelop and it compiles our complete solution, in 18 seconds. Similar timing with MSBuild.

My guess is that VS is trying to find out if the project needs a compile, but this process is about 15 times slower than actually performing the compile!!

I can't switch to the great sharpdevelop, it lacks some small, but essential requirements for our debugging scenarios.

Can I prevent VS from checking this project, And have it compile the projects without such a check, just like sharpdevelop?

I already know about unchecking projects in configuration management to prevent building some projects, but my developers will forget they need to compile this project after updating to latest sources and they face problems that seem strange to them.

Edit: Interesting results of an investigation: The delay happens to one of the projects only. In configuration manager I unchecked all projects, then compiled each of them individually. All projects compile in a few seconds!! The point is this: if that special project is built directly, compiles in a few seconds, if it is being built (or skipped, because it is up-to-date) as a result of building another project that depends on it, VS hangs for about a minute and half, and then decides to compile it (or skip it). My conclusion: Visual studio is checking to know if any files are changed, but for some reasons, for this special project it is extremely inefficient!!

Comment: Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions => Build and run -> MsBuild project build output verbosity: Diagnostic. Maybe it will tell at what point VS hangs. Also VsColorOutput plugin can be helpful.

Comment: @apocalypse Thanks l’ll check this.